# Disposing of CompositionContainer takes very long time

Tags: c#, mef

Company software is using MEF to load one plugin.

Desposing of CompositionContainer is either instant or takes up to 10 seconds.

What might be the reason of that? How to debug that?

Comment: Use a profiler, we cant tell what is happening in your code, or why. It may give you some clues to whats going on underneath

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: Sorry, I cannot do that. To clarify - I'm loading external dll to which source code I don't have access so I don't know why disposing of that dll takes such a long time.